# xargs wc -l reports two totals

Tags: bash, xargs, wc

I want to calculate all lines in the directory `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas`.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas
find  -name '*.*' |xargs  wc -l
536577 total
```

Write the two lines as one line.

```
 find  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas  -name '*.*' |xargs wc -l
```

[image]

bash output two `total` number,one is `495736` ,the other is `40841`,

```
495736 + 40841 = 536577
```

Why bash do not give only one total `536577` at the bottom such as `find  -name '*.*' |xargs  wc -l` do?

Comment: Is really "*.*" what you want? You are requesting file names containing a dot, those which don't will not be accounted for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[POSIX xargs spec.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) says:

> The generated command line length shall be the sum of the size in bytes of the utility name and each argument treated as strings, including a null byte terminator for each of these strings. **The xargs utility shall limit the command line length such that when the command line is invoked, the combined argument and environment lists shall not exceed `{ARG_MAX}-2048` bytes.**

That means; in your case, find's output does not fit in ARG_MAX‒2048 bytes, thus xargs aggregates it into 2 sets and invokes wc once for each set.

---

Take this pipeline for example, in an ideal world its output would be 1, but it's not.

```
seq 1000000 | xargs echo | wc -l
```

seq's output is 6888896 bytes.

```
$ seq 1000000 | wc -c
6888896
```

My *environment list* take up 558 bytes (ignoring that `_` is dynamic and whether the implementation takes terminating null pointers into consideration for the sake of clarity).

```
$ env | wc -c
558
```

`ARG_MAX` on my system is 131072 bytes.

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
131072
```

Now xargs have 131072‒2048‒558 = 128466 bytes; `echo` plus null delimiter takes up 5 bytes, so a space of 128461 bytes is left. Therefore we can say, xargs will have to invoke `echo` 6888896/128461 = ~54 times. Let's see if that's the case:

```
$ seq 1000000 | xargs echo | wc -l
54
```

Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with `xargs` running the command multiple times by adding an `awk` bit to the pipeline:

```
find wherever -name "*.*" -type f -print0 | \
xargs -0 wc -l | \
awk '$2 == "total" { total += $1 } END { print "Overall total", total } 1'
```

(Assuming GNU `find` and `xargs` or other implementations that understand `-print0` and `-0` respectively; otherwise filenames with spaces etc. in them can cause problems).

GNU `find` and maybe other implementations can skip the `xargs`, actually:

```
find wherever -name "*.*" -type f -exec wc -l '{}' '+'
```

will have the same effect as using `xargs` to run `wc` on multiple files at a time.

Comment: @oguzismail It's in posix now? Nice. -- And I know that. I left out irrelevant bits.